# Random bug with settings menu not loading on SP Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx-extensions

I'm getting a random bug when my Settings menu (Gear icon in the top right corner) does not appear sometimes on my SP Online site. I found that when it happens I have an error in my console (see below).

When I refresh the page it is all good, if I refresh 10 times, I'm getting this problem 2-3 times. Looks like some race condition is involved. I've traced the error and it looks like a bug in SP JavaScript code.
It all looks like:

[image]

Here are all details about the error:

The console error:
[image: This error I see in console]

Here is the piece of code where the bug sits:
[image]

So line `return e.Id === n.newWorkloadSettingLink.Id` fails because `e` sometimes `null`. I traced the source of `e` and it looks like it an iteration from `_spPageContextInfo.MenuData.SettingsData` array + merged with something else (+5 more elements) where one element is `null` in my case (item with index 3).

[image]

If I'm fast enough (can include script which runs on a page before the error call) and run the following block of code on Init in my Application Customizer extension, error disappears:

```
    const links = _spPageContextInfo.MenuData.SettingsData;
    for (let i=0; i < links.length; i++) {
      if (!links[i]) {
        links.splice(i, 1); // Removing item if it has no value
      }
    }
```

But this is kind of hack, and obviously, I need some help to understand how to resolve this issue for good. Does anyone have any idea why do I have one element in the array set to `null` or why Microsoft has this bug?

PS.: I play with SP on my own non-commertial research project and don't have any MS support subscription. Anyway I don't believe they will fix this bug for me in shot time as they are a bit slow sometimes. My last hope that someone from the community already saw/solved something like this :)
Thanks everyone in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You should open a support ticket via the Microsoft 365 Admin center. All plans have support via this mechanism. As you noted, there is nothing we can do to help.